Is there any hope for this shower grout short of replacement?
Conventional cleaning products don't seem to make a dent...

Have you tried a bleach based cleaner and did you allow it time to sink in before scrubbing it out?   Please give us details about what you already have done, that did not work.

This question is similar to: Best way to remove grout stains in shower?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Also How do I treat mold and mildew in shower grout?.
